# Stripe add postal/ zip in android CardInputWidget

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

how can I add postal / zip code for stripe CardInputWidget I was able to achieve this with CardMultilineWidget but I need this in a single line right now I can enter the card number, MM/YY & CVV I also need a place to enter a zip code.

```
<com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
 android:id="@+id/card_input_widget"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Not clear to me at all, probably to others as well. Can you please post the picture of how CardInputWidget looks

Comment: @deathangel908 can you have a look

Comment: I don't know about how CardInputWidget works, but you can extend CardInputWidget and use findViewById in this component to find the view you need to set text into.

Comment: Unfortunately, the CardInputWidget doesn't support zipcode entry.  You'd probably want to make your own widget.  The library is open source though, so you could maybe do that fairly easily.  https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/view/CardInputWidget.java

Answer (score 6):

Set   cardInputWidget.postalCodeEnabled=false in class to hide postal code